# emacs lisp: insert string removes the whitespace

Tags: emacs, elisp

I want to insert a string in the current buffer. My function works fine with emacs -q, but for some reason does not with my configuration: the whitespace at the end of "import " is ignored. The inserted text is `importos` instead of `import os`.

```
(defun my-python-import-add (to_import)
     (interactive "swhat to import ? ")
     (beginning-of-buffer)
     ;; save point
     ;; go to beginning of imports
     (newline)
     (insert "import " to_import)  ;; works with emacs -q
     ;; and call py-isort
     )
```

So is there a more solid way to insert the string ? (I'd like to avoid debugging my config file…)

I tried with

```
(insert (concat "import " to_import))
```

or with `s.el`

```
 (insert s-join " " '("import" to_import))
```

with no success. 
This is so basic…

Thanks !

ps: I know about `rope-auto-import`.

Comment: If you insert a string with a whitespace, the full string, with the whitespace will be inserted into the buffer. You must be doing something else wrong -- maybe you have an old byte-compiled version of the file laying around?

Comment: I had a pyc laying around, deleting it changes nothing. Maybe it's because of a mode, like an "auto remove trailing whitespace". It isn't easy to investigate.

Comment: Lyndydancer was referring to a ".elc" file: emacs load the byte compiled files when present (if they are old, it prints message but the byte compiled file has preference).  What if you rename your function in the init file?  Can you use the old function after restarting emacs despite the renaming?

Comment: Oh I see. I wrote my function in `ielm` mode, so I don't have a related .elc file.

Answer (score 0):

More confident with your comments, I investigated and found out that a supposedly non-working function had this side effect. It tried to add `delete-trailing-whitespace` to the `before-save-hook`.